# Mingw-w64 toolchain for Bazel (Ubuntu 20.04.1 )

Tags: c++, ubuntu, bazel, mingw-w64

I am trying to create my toolchain for mingw-w64 on Ubuntu with Bazel. I am following this tutorial: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/tutorial/cc-toolchain-config.html. However, when I try to adapt the compiler's paths to the paths of my mingw64 installation I get the following error:

```
bazel build --config=mingw_config -s //main:hello-world --verbose_failures
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
INFO: Analyzed target //main:hello-world (16 packages loaded, 46 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
SUBCOMMAND: # //main:hello-world [action 'Compiling main/hello-world.cc', configuration: a79594d39f0782b210e102e89b8a67dda26e295f95805aa9c0140f6281fdd3f5, execution platform: @local_config_platform//:host]
(cd /home/federica/.cache/bazel/_bazel_federica/fb36143429cca4c38e61a5e83150e333/execroot/__main__ && \
  exec env - \
    PATH=/home/federica/.cache/bazelisk/downloads/bazelbuild/bazel-3.5.0-linux-x86_64/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin \
    PWD=/proc/self/cwd \
  /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -MD -MF bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/main/_objs/hello-world/hello-world.d '-frandom-seed=bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/main/_objs/hello-world/hello-world.o' -iquote . -iquote bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin -iquote external/bazel_tools -iquote bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/bazel_tools -c main/hello-world.cc -o bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/main/_objs/hello-world/hello-world.o)
SUBCOMMAND: # //main:hello-world [action 'Linking main/hello-world', configuration: a79594d39f0782b210e102e89b8a67dda26e295f95805aa9c0140f6281fdd3f5, execution platform: @local_config_platform//:host]
(cd /home/federica/.cache/bazel/_bazel_federica/fb36143429cca4c38e61a5e83150e333/execroot/__main__ && \
  exec env - \
    PATH=/home/federica/.cache/bazelisk/downloads/bazelbuild/bazel-3.5.0-linux-x86_64/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin \
    PWD=/proc/self/cwd \
  /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/main/hello-world bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/main/_objs/hello-world/hello-world.o -Wl,-S -lstdc++)
ERROR: /home/federica/examples/cpp_mingw_toolchain/stage1/main/BUILD:3:10: output 'main/hello-world' was not created
ERROR: /home/federica/examples/cpp_mingw_toolchain/stage1/main/BUILD:3:10: not all outputs were created or valid
Target //main:hello-world failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 9.390s, Critical Path: 0.58s
INFO: 2 processes: 2 linux-sandbox.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

and if I look inside `bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/main/hello-world`the executable is not created.
However, if I try to run in the bash the single command indicated from the verbose_failures:

```
cd /home/federica/.cache/bazel/_bazel_federica/fb36143429cca4c38e61a5e83150e333/execroot/__main__ && \
  exec env - \
    PATH=/home/federica/.cache/bazelisk/downloads/bazelbuild/bazel-3.5.0-linux-x86_64/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin \
    PWD=/proc/self/cwd \
  /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/main/hello-world bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/main/_objs/hello-world/hello-world.o -Wl,-S -lstdc++
```

the executable 'Hello-world.exe' is created succesfully.

Any suggestion on what is going wrong?

Below, my toolchain BUILD file

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

cc_toolchain_suite(
    name = "mingw_suite",
    toolchains = {
        "k8": ":k8_toolchain",
    },
)



filegroup(name = "empty")

cc_toolchain(
    name = "k8_toolchain",
    toolchain_identifier = "k8-toolchain",
    toolchain_config = ":k8_toolchain_config",
    all_files = ":empty",
    compiler_files = ":empty",
    dwp_files = ":empty",
    linker_files = ":empty",
    objcopy_files = ":empty",
    strip_files = ":empty",
    supports_param_files = 0,
)

load(":cc_toolchain_config.bzl", "cc_toolchain_config")
cc_toolchain_config(name = "k8_toolchain_config")
```

and the cc_toolchain_config.bzl:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/cc:action_names.bzl", "ACTION_NAMES")
   # NEW
load(
    "@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:cc_toolchain_config_lib.bzl",
    "feature",
    "flag_group",
    "flag_set",
    "tool_path",
)

all_link_actions = [ # NEW
    ACTION_NAMES.cpp_link_executable,
    ACTION_NAMES.cpp_link_dynamic_library,
    ACTION_NAMES.cpp_link_nodeps_dynamic_library,
]


def _impl(ctx):
    tool_paths = [ # NEW
        tool_path(
            name = "gcc",
            path = "/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc",
        ),
        tool_path(
            name = "ld",
            path = "/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld",
        ),
        tool_path(
            name = "ar",
            path = "/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld",
        ),
        tool_path(
            name = "cpp",
            path = "/bin/false",
        ),
        tool_path(
            name = "gcov",
            path = "/bin/false",
        ),
        tool_path(
            name = "nm",
            path = "/bin/false",
        ),
        tool_path(
            name = "objdump",
            path = "/bin/false",
        ),
        tool_path(
            name = "strip",
            path = "/bin/false",
        ),
    ]
    
    
    
    features = [ # NEW
        feature(
            name = "default_linker_flags",
            enabled = True,
            flag_sets = [
                flag_set(
                    actions = all_link_actions,
                    flag_groups = ([
                        flag_group(
                            flags = [
                                "-lstdc++",
                            ],
                        ),
                    ]),
                ),
            ],
        ),
    ]
    return cc_common.create_cc_toolchain_config_info(
        ctx = ctx,
        features = features, # NEW
        cxx_builtin_include_directories = [ # NEW
        "/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include",
        "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/include/c++",
        "/usr/share/mingw-w64/include",
        "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/include",
        "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/include-fixed",
        "/usr/include",
        ],        
        toolchain_identifier = "k8-toolchain",
        host_system_name = "local",
        target_system_name = "local",
        target_cpu = "k8",
        target_libc = "unknown",
        compiler = "i686-w64-mingw32-gcc",
        abi_version = "unknown",
        abi_libc_version = "unknown",
        tool_paths = tool_paths,
    )

cc_toolchain_config = rule(
    implementation = _impl,
    attrs = {},
    provides = [CcToolchainConfigInfo],
)
```

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is relatively easy to miss, but actually already included in your question, the error says `hello-world` has not been created, while `hello-world.exe` has apparently been produced just fine. That is, we've actually built a file with the `.exe` suffix, but did not tell `bazel` through it's toolchain config that is the case and it failed expecting output without it.

To address that, you can also load: `artifact_name_pattern` from `@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:cc_toolchain_config_lib.bzl` with the other symbols and then set `artifact_name_patterns` attribute of `cc_common.create_cc_toolchain_config_info()`:

```
artifact_name_patterns = [
    artifact_name_pattern(
        category_name = "executable",
        prefix = "",
        extension = ".exe",
    ),
]
```